# Can't empty input field after submit in React

Tags: reactjs

I try some similar solutions I find on stack overflow but nothing seems to work, this is minor problem and according to code it should work, only problem that is puzzling me is maybe that after I submit the form app control is handed over to parent class, one level up which has nothing to do with state, and my setState method is called after this.props.api method in child component, I hope someone could help me with this one...

HERE IS THE CODE FROM CHILD

```
class UserInput extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }  

    onFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.api(this.state.value);
        this.setState({
            value:''
          });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <TextField onChange={this.handleChange}
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Image Search"
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    style={{minWidth:'500px'}}
                    type="text"
                    /><br></br>
                    <Button 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    >
```

AND THIS IS CODE FROM PARENT CLASS

```
class App extends React.Component {

  async onFormSubmit(term){
    const res = await axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos', {
      params:{query: term},
      headers:{
          Authorization: 'Client-ID'
      }
    });
    console.log(res.data.results)
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <UserInput api={this.onFormSubmit}/>
      <List/>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I would like to empty input field after I submit the form

Comment: Wherr are you using the state value? It doesn't even go to the text field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not binded your `TextField` with state value,

```
<TextField 
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    value={this.state.value}  //Provide value here
    id="outlined-name"
    label="Image Search"
    margin="normal"
    variant="outlined"
    style={{minWidth:'500px'}}
    type="text"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the value of input field because there is no binding with the value of text field to the state value so it's not updating the value of text field..

```
<TextField
    value = {this.state.value}
/>
```

Comment: please consider adding some explanation with your answer.

Comment: sure...there is no binding with the value of text field to the state value so it's not updating the value of text field...i'll consider it next time. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time :) could you kindly edit your answer and add those there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the value field in the TextField.
Try:

```
<TextField
    value = {this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    id="outlined-name"
    label="Image Search"
    margin="normal"
    variant="outlined"
    style={{minWidth:'500px'}}
    type="text"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render function should be something like this, where Textfield value is coming from state.

```
render() {
const { value } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
      <TextField
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        id="outlined-name"
        label="Image Search"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        value={value}
        style={{ minWidth: "500px" }}
        type="text"
      />
      <br />
      <button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

}